# second order non homogeneous differential equation, nonhomogeneous part stuck

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

there is second order nonhomogeneous differential equation 
$x^2y"-3xy'+4y=log x$ 
 and i have to find the solution
my attempt : 
first i found solution for the homogeneous equation, it is a repeated root so
$yp=Ax^2lnx+Bx^2$
here for the nonhomgenous i used variation parameter

$y1= x^2ln x$ and $y2=x^2$
using Wronski and cramer rule: 
$yp=u1.y1+u2.y2$ 
 
W=$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
    x^2lnx & x^2 \\
     2xlnx+x & 2x
  \end{array} \right] $
$=-x^3$ 
W1=$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & x^2 \\
     log x & 2x
  \end{array} \right]$
$=-x^2lnx$

W2=$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     x^2lnx & 0 \\
     2xlnx+x & log x
  \end{array} \right]$
$=x^2ln^2x$ 
$u'=\frac{W_1}{W}\frac{-x^2lnx}{-x^3}=\frac{lnx}{x}$
$u'=\frac{W_2}{W}\frac{x^2ln^2x}{-x^3}=\frac{-ln^2x}{x}$

integrate to find  u1, u2 
$u1=\frac{1}{2}ln^2x$ 
$u1=-\frac{1}{3}ln^3x$ 
$yp=u1.y1+u2.y2$

$=\frac{1}{2}ln^2x$$.x^2lnx$ $-\frac{1}{3}ln^3x$ $.x^2$
$=x^2ln^3x\frac{1}{6}$ 

 is this right??? 
however the book said that the answer is $y=x^2(Alogx+B)+\frac{1}{4}(logx+1)$
why this is not the same??

Answer (score 0):

This kind of equations are called Euler equations see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation#Second_order_.E2.80.93_solution_through_change_of_variables)
Substitute $x=e^t\rightarrow t=\log x$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dt}{dx}}=\dfrac{1}{e^t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

and

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^{-2t}\left(\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)$

Plug all this in the given equation

$x^2y''-3xy'+4y=\log x$

and get
$$e^{2t}e^{-2t}\left(\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)-3e^t\left(\dfrac{1}{e^t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)+4y=\log e^t$$
simplify 
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-4\dfrac{dy}{dt}+4y=t$$
which is a constant coefficients equation and I am sure you can go on easily by yourself. Get the solution for $y(t)$
$$y(t)=A e^{2 t}+B t 2 e^{2 t} +\frac{t+1}{4}$$
plug back $t=\log x$ and get the solution in $x$
$$y(x)=x^2\left(A+B\log x\right)+\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\log x+1\right)$$

hope this helps

Comment: hello thanks for answering my question, i got the homogeneous equation same as yours as it is repeated root, because it is euler, so $yp=Ax^2lnx+Bx^2$ but here i try to find solution for nonhomogeneous by using variation parameter and the result is not $+\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\log x+1\right)$, how you get this? can you elaborate more?